# Flutter/Dart How to access the orders from Woocommerce API using Flutter?

Tags: api, flutter, dart, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am following this Git: https://github.com/samarthagarwal/woocommerce_dart.
I am accessing the Woocommerce, but I am not taking the data from it.
Here is the part of the code I am using to access the Woocommerce and trying to display the data in the Flutter programm.
Hope someone can help me!!!

```
WooCommerceAPI wooCommerceAPI = WooCommerceAPI(
        url: "http://website.com/",
        consumerKey: "ck_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        consumerSecret: "cs_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");

 
    List<Technician> techies = [];
    // Get data using the "orders" endpoint
    var data = await wooCommerceAPI.getAsync("orders");
    var jsonData = json.decode(data.body);
    for (var u in jsonData) {
        Technician myTechy = Technician(u["id"].toString(), u["status"].toString(), u["first_name"], u["last_name"]);

        techies.add(myTechy);
      }
    return techies;
```

And here is the class

```
class Technician {
  final String id;
  final String status;
  final String first_name;
  final String last_name;
  // String status;
  //int rating;
  //String occupation;

  Technician(this.id, this.status, this.first_name, this.last_name);
}
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem here

Answer (score 0):

You're using woocommerce_api library which is a little confusing, try to use woocommerce library instead.
You can find it [here](https://pub.dev/packages/woocommerce)
This is the code I use to fetch Products from the website:

`WooCommerce wooCommerce = WooCommerce(                                                       baseUrl: 'http://website.com/', consumerKey: 'ck_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', consumerSecret: 'cs_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', );`

`Future getProducts() async {                                                                      var products= await wooCommerce.getProductCategories(                                      perPage: 30,                                                                                       );                                                                                            return products;                                                                                     }`